# How to get a GeoPosition of a clicked position on the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm doing some maths calculations in android map activity and I need to find a position of a GeoPoint which user has clicked on the map. I understand that I need to use onTouch event handler. This is how it looks like at the moment:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        GeoPoint pGoal = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());

        DisplayInfoMessage("The screen has been touched!" + event.getX() + " AND " + event.getY() + "Latitude: "+ pGoal.getLatitudeE6());   // only for displaying test popup

    }
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;        

}
```

It doesn't do what I want though. Any help or hint at least greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I've just answered it myself and the answer is the code which I provided. I'm leaving it here in case someone else will need it.

Comment: Ok we know what it doesnt do, but what does you code give you back?

Comment: Actually it's already doing what I wanted Warren. It's giving me a geoPoint basing on the position of user's click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this already is the answer:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            GeoPoint pGoal = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());

            DisplayInfoMessage("The screen has been touched!" + event.getX() + " AND " + event.getY() + "Latitude: "+ pGoal.getLatitudeE6());   // only for displaying test popup

        }
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;        

    }
```